# Correct approach to return API JSON response?

Tags: json, spring-boot, api

I'm building a backend API for a social network project.

There's a post, which includes likes and comments, comments include likes and replies and all of them belong to a user.

My question is, when fetching a post, do i include everything else such as:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin faucibus, lectus vel mollis iaculis, nisl lacus faucibus mi, sit amet commodo nibh odio id tortor.",
    "media": null,
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "john",
                "lastName": "dog",
                "username": "jonnyy",
                "email": "newFreshEmail@email.com",
                "country": {
                    "id": "MA",
                    "name": "Morocco"
                },
                "pictureFilePath": null,
                "birthDate": "1600-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "creationDate": "2022-11-19T23:00:00Z"
            },
            "replies": [],
            "likes": [],
            "creationDate": "2022-11-18T23:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "content": "Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo.",
            "user": {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Alice",
                "lastName": "cat",
                "username": "ALICEEE",
                "email": "newFreshEmail@email.com",
                "country": {
                    "id": "AL",
                    "name": "Albania"
                },
                "pictureFilePath": null,
                "birthDate": "1600-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "creationDate": "2022-11-20T22:43:56Z"
            },
            "replies": [],
            "likes": [],
            "creationDate": "2022-11-17T23:00:00Z"
        }
    ],,
    "likes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "john",
                "lastName": "dog",
                "username": "jonnyy",
                "email": "newFreshEmail@email.com",
                "country": {
                    "id": "MA",
                    "name": "Morocco"
                },
                "pictureFilePath": null,
                "birthDate": "1600-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "creationDate": "2022-11-19T23:00:00Z"
            },
            "creationDate": "2022-11-19T23:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user": {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Alice",
                "lastName": "cat",
                "username": "ALICEEE",
                "email": "newFreshEmail@email.com",
                "country": {
                    "id": "AL",
                    "name": "Albania"
                },
                "pictureFilePath": null,
                "birthDate": "1600-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "creationDate": "2022-11-20T22:43:56Z"
            },
            "creationDate": "2022-11-18T23:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "creationDate": "2022-11-19T23:00:00Z"
}
```

Or keep it simple and just return something like so:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin faucibus, lectus vel mollis iaculis, nisl lacus faucibus mi, sit amet commodo nibh odio id tortor.",
    "media": null,
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            "replies": [],
            "likes": [],
            "creationDate": "2022-11-18T23:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "content": "Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo.",
            "replies": [],
            "likes": [],
            "creationDate": "2022-11-17T23:00:00Z"
        }
    ],,
    "likes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "creationDate": "2022-11-19T23:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "creationDate": "2022-11-18T23:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "creationDate": "2022-11-19T23:00:00Z"
}
```

Then fetch the user based on a particular id (be it post's, like's etc...) when needed?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on your need? As to what data to fetch, display and manipulate ?

Comment: @Harsh Yes you're right, I did mention its for a social network web app project but I think i had to be more specific. For example when loading the feed page where you find all posts alongside their likes and comments etc...

Comment: The question was whether i fetch all data at once or fetch post with ids for likes and comments then fetch the user who made those likes and comments based on their ids.

Comment: Actually after doing some research, I think the best approch is to use DTOs based on a feature to control which data is returned for which use case.